# Model validation fails on empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm passing a string representation of an object that posesses a list to a C# controller using Ajax. Things work fine when the list is filled but when it is empty model validation fails. 
The string i am passing is: `{"RoutingTags":[]"}`.

The class used for model validation is this:

```
public class RoutingTagsData
{
    [Required]
    public IList<RoutingTag> RoutingTags { get; set; }
}
```

The list is passed to the controller using Ajax and the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateOrUpdateRoutingTags(RoutingTagsData routingTagsData)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    // stuff
}
```

The model validation fails, however, because `routingTagsData` is null.

What can i do to make `routingTagsData` be an object with an empty list, without instantiating it myself if it is null in the controller?

Comment: Why leave it null in the controller and not assign a default type which can then be overwritten in your request ?

Comment: My problem is mostly that the argument passed with ajax does contain an object with a list, just that list is empty. I don't want to instantiate anything myself if possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @John said you can initialize the list to solve your problem. And you are not doing it inside your controller.

```
public class RoutingTagsData
{
    [Required]
    public IList<RoutingTag> RoutingTags { get; set; } = new List<RoutingData>( ) ;
}
```

But if you are sure that the binding is done properly and you want to use the null but the validation fails. Just clear the Modelstate errors and continue with your logic or simply create a ModelBinder for your RoutingTagsData and you can decide what to do there(include errors on the ModelState or not in the case the list is null), you can also initialize the list there after mvc does the call to the ModelBinder but I would not recommend to do that.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> without instantiating it myself if it is null in the controller?

If the list being `null` is unexpected - and I would definitely argue that all collection types should never be `null` - then the real problem is that you're allowing `RoutingTagsData` to be initialised in a bad state to begin with.

Default initialisation should be handled by a class's default constructor:

```
public class RoutingTagsData
{
    public RoutingTagsData()
    {
        RoutingTags = new List<RoutingTag>();
    }

    [Required]
    public IList<RoutingTag> RoutingTags { get; set; }
}
```

which solves the problem.